# Setting first letter of a sentence as capitals

Tags: formatting

Can the first letter of a new sentence be automatically made capitals like in word

Then I do not have to capitalise each and every time

Comment: One big advantage of most editors is that they don't guess what you mean, but do as you say. Every time I use MS Wort I have to fight against it because it sucks at guessing what I mean. Why would you want this? Upper casing a single letter isn't that hard, in fact you can type much faster if the editor just does what you say and doesn't guess what you mean, because you don't have to check on every word whether Wort got it correct. tl;dr: learn to use the shift key, you'll be better of that way (sorry if this is not helpful at all).

Comment: The answer is yes.

Comment: @JPi The floor is all yours

Comment: Just compare my necessary input for the short sentence "The 1., 2. and 3. harmonic are important.". My editor of choice gets the following input: `The 1., 2. and 3. harmonic are important.`. If I want to type that in MS Wort I input: `The 1., 2. and <C-left><delete>a<end>3. harmonic <C-left><delete>h<end>are important.` Do you really want that for your editor?

Comment: I know that it can be done, but don't know how to do it in the editor itself.  With LuaLaTeX you could write a script to achieve that in the output, but as @Skillmon has pointed out, this is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @Skillmon I see what you mean